# pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32 in windows7 64 bit environment

Tags: python-3.x, pypy

Using PyPy Interpreter under Windows 64 bit
Is it possible to load a 64 bit dll in pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32 in windows7 64 bit environment?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely.  PyPy on Windows is only 32-bit.

http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/windows.html#what-is-missing-for-a-full-64-bit-translation